# Pinia + Vue 3 state reactivity - alternative to storeToRefs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia, vue-reactivity

I have the following composable `useLocations.js`:

```
export const useLocations = defineStore('useLocations', () => {
    const state = reactive({
        data: 1
    })

    const update = () => {
        state.data = 2
    }

    return {
        ...toRefs(state),
        update
    }
})
```

and I am accesing it in my `locations.vue` component like this:

```
const { data, update } = useLocations
update()
console.log(data) // 1
```

I am expecting `console.log(data)` to be `2` not `1`

I have tried to access the store like this, and this indeed works:

```
const store = useLocations()
const { data } = storeToRefs(store)
const { update } = store
update()
console.log(data) // 2
```

but I would like a solution without `storeToRefs`, and I don't understand why `toRefs` in the composable doesn't work.

According to Vue documentation https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs this is my exact scenario, and the reactivity breaks somehow.

LE: I would like a solution without `storeToRefs` so I can avoid calling the store twice in my component, once for state and once for the actions.

Comment: Why not `storeToRefs`. At the end It's a JavaScript thing that can cause reactivity to be lost.

Comment: @WaleedTariq because I would have to call the store once for the state and once for the actions. If toRefs kept the reactivity as vue documentations says it does then I could call the store only once in my component. I just don't understand why it doesn't when vue says it does.

Comment: The internal workings of Pinia dictates the need for a special `storeToRefs` function that acts similarly to `toRefs` but is specifically designed for Pinia.  "I dont want to" isn't a great reason for not wanting to use a function that seems to do exactly what you want. Maybe you can explain your case more.

Comment: @yoduh The reason I would like a solution without storeToRefs is having to avoid calling the store twice in my component, once for only the states, once for the actions/getters.

Comment: @Enthusiasm Getters are handled with storeToRefs too. I suppose there's no demand for this in general because storeToRefs is primarily used when we need refs, e.g. for v-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toRefs` doesn't serve a good purpose inside store setup function because it unwraps all the refs that are returned. Notice that `console.log(data)` outputs "1" and not a ref. It's works the same way as [the refs inside `reactive`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-as-reactive-object-property), as Pinia uses Vue reactivity internally.

It's unnecessary to destructure a store, it can be used as `store.data` and `store.update`. Otherwise `storeToRefs` is supposed to be used as in the question, this produces no overhead.

In case you need to modify this behaviour for some reason, custom helper can be created that will add additional keys to `storeToRefs` object based on certain criteria, e.g. for actions:

```
const storeToRefsWithActions = store => ({
  ...storeToRefs(store),
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(store)
    .filter(
      ([key, val]) => !key.startsWith('$') && typeof val === 'function'
    )
  )
})
```

Comment: Thank you for explaning, this helper helps me achieve my purpose.